# WordPress CSS: Site Title changing from Sans serif to Serif

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm going to start with saying I'm a total noob in coding school and to please be kind. I'm attempting to help my husband with his blog: https://directionandpace.com/ There is an issue with the title Direction and Pace.

First, he asked if I can remove title link that redundantly links back to the page. There isn't a way to easily edit WordPress HTML (just the stylesheet) so I thought I'd figure that out later and just change the link color to black instead of blue. ;)

Second, we both realized that when you click on the second page "Who We Are" the title changes to a non bold serif and ITS DRIVING ME CRAZY.

Code Below:

What should be just the body and the only Serif in the CSS:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
color: #776f6f;
font-family: Merriweather, Georgia, serif;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 2;
}
```

The CSS for the Title:

```
.entry-title {
font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: 700;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Is it somehow assuming the entire second page (including the title) is the body? Halp.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that on your homepage that text is wrapped in a `<h1>` element but in the who-we-are page it's wrapped in a `<p>` element. Your CSS has the rule:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

that is applied on the homepage but not on the who-we-are page. Easiest solution would be to update the code or template for the who-we-are page to change the `<p>` to a `<h1>` to match the home page.

Home page heading HTML:

```
<div id="site-identity">
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="https://directionandpace.com/" rel="home">Direction &amp; Pace</a></h1>
    <p class="site-description">Explore. Experience. Always.</p>
</div>
```

Who we are heading HTML:

```
<div id="site-identity">
    <p class="site-title"><a href="https://directionandpace.com/" rel="home">Direction &amp; Pace</a></p>
    <p class="site-description">Explore. Experience. Always.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The title on the main page is wrapped in a heading tag, so it's getting the correct heading styling:

`<h1 class="site-title"><a href="https://directionandpace.com/" rel="home">Direction &amp; Pace</a></h1>`

However, the title on the about page is wrapped in a `<p>` tag, so it's getting the body styling:

`<p class="site-title"><a href="https://directionandpace.com/" rel="home">Direction &amp; Pace</a></p>`

Comment: Thank you for your help!